# Does Microsoft provide offline API documentation for .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net-4.0

Does Microsoft provide offline API documentation for .NET 4.0 (C#, VB.NET, and C++)? The latest I can find on MSDN is .NET 3.5 SP1. I am more interested in the class library than the examples and articles on proper usage, though these would be desirable to have when I am not able to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Visual Studio's built-in Help Viewer can download as much of MSDN as you want.

Open Help Viewer, then click Manage Content

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

If you install Visual Studio, you also install a tool called the [Help Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh580782.aspx).

There, you can download any MSDN documentation (4.0 included) for offline use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Once you install the HTML Help Viewer, click the "Contents" button from the toolbar, from there you can select what documentation you want to download to your local machine.